# Создать функцию, конвертирующую полученный из инпута список в строчку

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, текст, преобразование

Хэлп!

Нужно создать функцию, которая получает в качестве аргумента массив слов, а возвращает корректное предложение, составленное из этих слов.

Функции нужно:

1. Начинать предложение с заглавной буквы.
2. В конце предложения должна стоять точка.
3. Между словами должен быть пробел.
4. Не выполнять никаких других действий над словами.

Например:

- Вход: `["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]`
- Выход: `"I am the boss."`

Мои мысли:

```
def sentencify(): #Создал функцию, тут все ясно.
    n = input('Your text here: ') #здесь будет инпут
    a = [] #а вот дальше не совсем понятно. Нужен пустой список чтобы в него передать инпут? тогда
    a[n] = a[n].capitalize() #тут понятно делаем заглавную первую.
    return " ".join(a)+'.'#этим собираем строку из списка с точкой на конце
print(a) #так как в переменную а  переданы данные с инпут и сделаны все манипуляции (капиталайз, и джойнт)
```

Прошу уважаемых знатоков, по возможности, не только правильный ответ указать, но и прокомментировать/исправить мои мысли.

**UPD:**
благодарю за терпение! Осталась с инпутом неясность.

```
def sentencify(words): 
    return ' '.join(words).capitalize() + '.' 
    words = input() #вот тут надо что-то добавить
print(sentencify(words)) #[ " i " , " a m " , " t h e " , " b o s s " ].или тут.
```

**UPD:2** Работает. Благодарю Вас!

```
def sentencify(words):
     return ' '.join(words).capitalize() + '.'
import ast
words = ast.literal_eval(input())
print(sentencify(words))
```

Comment: вы не написали как данные попадают в `input`, поэтому написал свой вариант. Или у вас действительно из input приходит строка `'["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]'`? или вы пишете в консоль текст 'i am the Boss` и из этой строки нужно получить `["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]`, чтобы в дальнейшем преобразовать?

Comment: Хочется чтобы ["i", "am", "the", "Boss"] (и любые другие списки). можно было вставить, ввести в input. А на выходе получить строку капиталайз с точкой.

Comment: обновил ответ, добавив пример

Comment: блин, я вставил в консоль `["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]`, как вы и хотели. Или как нужно?

Comment: Вставляем в инпут ["i", "am", "the", "Boss"], а на выходе "I am the boss."

Comment: Принимайте ответ с финальными штрихами )

Comment: У вас правильно отступы поставлены? `import ast` и `words = ast.literal_eval(input())` не должны находиться внутри функции. У меня уже есть ответ с правильным работающим кодом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sentencify(words: list) -> str:
    return ' '.join(words).capitalize() + '.'
    
words = ["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]
print(sentencify(words))  # "I am the boss."

words = ["Hello", "World"]
print(sentencify(words))  # "Hello world."
```

Добавляем `input`:

```
import ast
words = ast.literal_eval(input())

print(sentencify(words))  # "I am the boss."
```

---

Вот так можно организовать ввод слов из консоли (ввод остановится после того как нажмете <kbd>Enter</kbd> на пустой строке):

```
words = []

while True:
    word = input()
    if not word:
        break

    words.append(word)

# Функция получает список слов и формирует текст
print(sentencify(words))
```

---

**UPD.** Если в консоль вводится прямо строка `["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]`, то:

```
import ast
words = ast.literal_eval(input())
print(type(words), words)
```

Консоль:

```
>> ["i", "am", "the", "Boss"]
<class 'list'> ['i', 'am', 'the', 'Boss']
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в первом блоке кода нет функции. Там уже заявлен список, который переводится в строку. Нет инпута. Второй блок выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Вот неповерю, что вы не сможете написать функцию :) Добавил функцию. У меня второй блок не выдает ошибку, да и не бывает одной ошибки на любые случаи, поэтому после фразы "выдаёт ошибку" добавляйте саму ошибку :)

Comment: @MR, если я ответил на ваш вопрос, примите ответ